# Prevent blur event on keyboard close

Tags: javascript, ios, web, keyboard

This is for mobile web apps, not native.

I have an autocomplete drop-down that closes on the blur event. But I want to prevent this from happening when the user closes the keyboard on mobile (ie the autocomplete dropdown should stay visible). Is there a way to distinguish a blur event caused by the keyboard closing, and other kinds of blur events? Can I prevent a blur event specifically caused by closing the keyboard in mobile?

Comment: Are you specifically triggering the autocomplete close on blur? If so, you can check the user agent for mobile, and not hide on blur event.

Comment: @GeorgeNemes But I still want autocomplete to close in mobile if they blur the normal way. Just not when they close the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first I would recommend checking your libraries' documentation because they might provide something in their API, although there's nothing I'm aware of. That's the disadvantage of Web Apps: you can't access native functionality.

If you still really want to do it, here's a possible solution. It's ugly, but it might work.

`Container on tap function (event)`

```
If !autocomplete return // if you cant see the popup do nothing and blur normally

If (event.target != inputID) AND (event.target != autocID)
CloseAutocomplete()`
```

Essentially, instead of closing the autocomplete on blur, close it whenever the user taps on your parent container, but not on the input itself or the autocomplete. Depending on how it works, you could extend it to check any tap on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I see you tagged iOS... you can observe keyboard events with UIKeyboardWillHideNotification.  [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIKeyboardWillHideNotification]  You may have to do and asynchronous delay to catch that event on with onblur, though.

If you really want to prevent all "other kinds of blur events" you could make your drop-down close on specific events (instead of on blur).  For example: when a another field is clicked, navigation, and/or add an 'x' close button next to that drop-down control.

Answer (score 0):

In the blur event listener, test for event.relatedTarget === null. If focus has moved to a different element, event.relatedTarget will refer to that element, but if there is no focus (as is the case when the cause of the blur is keyboard close), event.relatedTarget will be null.